# React function Component state - Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I'm new to React, I'm trying to learn React function Component state. I was wondering why we need to do `onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}` instead of `onClick={setCount(count + 1)}`

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function Counter() {
    const [count , setCount] = useState(0);
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={setCount(count+1)}> + </button>
            {count}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Counter;
```

Answer (score 4):

`setCount(count + 1)` will immediately call `setCount(count + 1)` every render. That will change the state of the component, forcing a new render, which will call `setCount()` again... you end up in an infinite render loop where the React runtime can never finish rendering the component (this is a simplified explanation).

`() => setCount(count + 1)` is an expression that defines a *function* that, when called, will call `setCount(count + 1)`. It does not call `setCount(count + 1)` itself, so there's no infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Dan gave a good answer that I think could be expanded upon. We can also extract the onClick function outside of the return block. This is useful if you need more complex logic for an event and want to keep your return block readable.

Now we have a variable `increment` that holds a function expression and we can simply pass it right to our `onClick` listener.

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const increment = () => {
    ...
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={increment}>+</button>
      {count}
    </div>
  );
}
```